# How to get new questions according to a specific tag(example: iPhone)

Tags: support, tags, questions

How can I get the new questions regarding each topic, so that I want share my known answers with them.

Comment: Just a suggestion, considering your "example: iPhone" in the title. You may want to search the ios tag in stead, since the iphone tag is intended specifically for questions relating to iphone hardware (although it's used incorrectly all the time). The ios tag is for iPod Touch, iPhone, iPad and Apple TV software. The objective-c tag should be useful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) your are interested in and sort questions by "newest".

So, if you are looking for the newest iphone and ipad questions checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone?sort=newest and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad?sort=newest.